# Creating Array With Swift (Segmentation fault:11 Error)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Im trying to retrieve a list of objects from my parse database but no matter what solution I try to come up with, I get an error "Segmentation fault: 11"

Here is the code I have been messing around with, I'm trying to set a list of workgroups to an array like this;

```
["Road Closure", "Damaged Roads and Streets", "Water and Sewage", "Landscaping", "Trash and Waste Management", "Crime", "Other"]
```

Here is my function.

```
  func getWorkgroups(){
        var testArray = [String]()
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Workgroups")
        let runkey = query.order(byAscending: "workgroup")
        runkey.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as [PFObject]!{
                    for object in objects {
                    let load = object.objectForKey("workgroup") as! String
                    self.testArray.append(load)
                    print(self.testArray)
                }
            }
            }else {
                }
            } as! PFQueryArrayResultBlock

    }
```

Comment: You want `if let objects = objects as [PFObject]` - No exclamation mark.  You can't cast an optional array of `PFObject` to a implicitly unwrapped optional array of `PFObject`.  You should also rethink your use of `as! String` - Any time you use ! you have an opportunity for a crash,

Comment: thanks for the reply. i fixed all of those things and im still getting the same error.

Comment: You should set an exception breakpoint to identify exactly which line it is crashing on and the full details of the exception message

Comment: thanks for your help i was able to figure this out using a different approach.